# phpMyAdmin - SQL window - support for context menu

Tags: phpmyadmin

In the phpMyAdmin - SQL window:

Why doesn't the SQL window support right-click copy/paste?

I have tried Ctrl C / Ctrl V but I'm so used to using right-click and selecting copy/paste

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is already [reported as a bug](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/13849) at the phpMyAdmin bug tracker. There's no fix there, but really the problem seems to be in the CodeMirror library code used by phpMyAdmin.